# Iterating through a single row of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My data happens to be in the form:

```
data = { "year" : 2001,
         "category 1": 1234, 
         "category 2": 2345, 
         "category 3": 3456, 
          ...
}
```

And so I'm going to be making a graphic with these lines of code:

```
  svg.selectAll("left.coord")
    .data(data) 
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("cy", function(d, i){
      return d[i]; //or whatever
    })
    .attr("cx", 0)
```

Basically, I need the function inside cy to return 1234, then 2345, then 3456, etc. I know how to do this if my data was an array of objects, but what do I do in this case? The code doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: You can get an array of values with `Object.values(data)`

Comment: `selectAll().data()` needs to be fed an array - not an object. As no array is provided, no items are entered and your function to set cy is never executed.